# Access 2016 Error 3464 while coding for Update button

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

In access 2016 I'm trying to use an update command.I'm creating a database as my internship project as I'm unfamiliar with the coding I have been struggling a lot. I'm referring to a video by Setha Iech: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ri2Y9-16AEo. When I'm using the below code an error continuously pops up

> Error 3464

```vb
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    'when we click on button Add there are two options
    '1. for insert
    '2. for update
    If Me.txtID.Tag & "" = "" Then
        'this is for insert new
        'add data to table
        CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Business(ID, Project_ID, [Date_of_Enquiry], Division, Client, Description, Probability_to_win,Status, [Proposal_Submission_date], [Expected_award_date], Remarks)" & _
                "VALUES ('" & Me.txtID & "','" & Me.txtProject_ID & "','" & Me.txtDate_of_Enquiry & "','" & Me.cboDivision & "','" & _
                Me.txtClient & "','" & Me.txtDescription & "','" & Me.cboProbability_to_win & "','" & Me.cboStatus & "','" & Me.txtProposal_Submission_date & "','" & Me.txtExpected_award_date & "','" & Me.txtRemarks & "')"
    Else
        'otherwise (Tag of txtID store the ID of statement to be modified)
    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Business" & _
    " SET ID=" & Me.txtID & _
    ", Project_ID='" & Me.txtProject_ID & "'" & _
    ", Date_of_Enquiry='" & Me.txtDate_of_Enquiry & "'" & _
    ", Division='" & Me.cboDivision & "'" & _
    ", Client='" & Me.txtClient & "'" & _
    ", Description='" & Me.txtDescription & "'" & _
    ", Probability_to_win='" & Me.cboProbability_to_win & "'" & _
    ", Status='" & Me.cboStatus & "'" & _
    ", Proposal_Submission_date='" & Me.txtProposal_Submission_date & "'" & _
    ", Expected_award_date='" & Me.txtExpected_award_date & "'" & _
    ", Remarks='" & Me.txtRemarks & "'" & _
    " WHERE ID=" & Me.txtID.Tag

    End If


'clear form
cmdClear_Click
'refresh data in list on form
databasesub.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

Thank you for your answers in advance

Comment: You would be much better off using a parameterized query to avoid many possible problems. The way you are doing it is really old and has several problems. One, Dates use `#` and not `'`  in Access. Another is what happens if txtDescription has a single quote in it? That's going to totally mess up your insert statement and your update statement. And is `Product_ID` really a string? You are using quotes, and ID's are typically numeric and cannot have quotes around them.

Comment: Note that if you use a bound form, all this code is not necessary, and updates and inserts are handled by Access itself. The only thing you need is `Me.Dirty = False` if you want to force the update (or nothing at all since Access will update when needed)

Comment: And to add... I wouldnt recommend using Youtube to learn how to code. Look at the date on that video... 2011 was 9 years ago.

Comment: @braX Nope, `Me.Dirty = False` clears the `Dirty` flag, which means any uncommited changes are pushed to the database. `Me.Dirty` is true if the current form contains uncommitted changes

Comment: @braX thanks for the suggestions but could you be more detailed about the problem in the coding. Actually I'm new to coding and not getting a clear view of your recommendation. Any further suggestions are welcome